# Java RegEx for match + n chars

Tags: java, regex

Can anyone provide me with a regex for this. I have already tried "match.{1}". It's not working.

I want to remove all strings starting with â€ and the immediate next character from a string.

I am trying to generate a string and it contains unwanted special characters. I want to remove them.

Example input will be like "Something â€% something else â€`something" and the expected output is "Something something else something".

Comment: Could you provide some sample strings and matches?

Comment: Could you please provide a little more information? It's really hard to tell what your asking.

Comment: This looks to me like an XY problem; that is, you have a byte stream which you try to read into a character stream using the wrong encoding. But then maybe I'm wrong... Can you prodive the context, please?

Comment: `str = str.replaceAll("(?s)â€.*$", "");`

Comment: @stribizhev it replaced all charactes after the first occurance. I just want to replace the immediate next character

Comment: @fge I am trying to convert a docx file to html using docx4j. But it produces some special charcters. I am trying to remove those

Comment: Of course, it is what you asked for. If not, clarify. Provide exact sample input, expected output, your attempt and explain what works wrong.

Comment: @stribizhev I just want to replace the immediate next character

Comment: Instead of `I want`s you should *provide exact sample input, expected output, your attempt and explain what works wrong*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94334/discussion-between-sumodh-s-and-stribizhev).

Comment: `str = str.replaceAll("(?s)â€.\\s*", "");`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with:

```
string.replaceAll("â€.", "");
```

for

> Something â€% something else â€`something

it should give you a output:

> Something something else something